# PHP-SYMFONY 3 (Why my form does not validate the request data?)

Tags: symfony, request

Everything is in the title, I tried to submit & validate a Symfony form but I can't.
When I track the request I find that the form did not send any data in the POST parameters (No Request Content, No POST parameters)!
My code is:

in the Controller:

```
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ResetType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxTypeTest;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedTypeTest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use gestionBundle\Models\rememberMe;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class DefaultController extends Controller
 {
  /**
   * @Route("/login",name="login")
   */
  public function loginAction(Request $request)
  {
    $p=new compte();
    $form=$this->createFormBuilder($p)

        ->add('mail',EmailType::class)
        ->add('password',PasswordType::class)
        ->add('login', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Login'))
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository=$em->getRepository('gestionBundle:compte');


    $session=$this->container->get('session');
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    if ($request->getMethod()=='POST'){


        $data = $request->request->all();
        $email = $data['form']['mail'];
        $password = $data['form']['password'];


$user=$repository>findOneBy(array('mail'=>$email,'password'=>$password));

       if($user)
       {


           $remember=$request->request->get('remember_me');

           if($remember=='remember me'){

                $rememberMe=new rememberMe();
               $rememberMe->setEmail($email);
               $rememberMe->setPassword($password);

               $session = new Session();
               $session->start();
               $session->set('rememberMe',$rememberMe);
           }

  return 
 $this>render('gestionBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('user'=>$user));
       }

       else{
           $this->addFlash('alerte','LOGIN/PASSWORD INCORRECTE.. RESSAYER !');


       }

   }
    else{

        if ($session->has('rememberMe')){
            echo 'cas contarire 2';
            $rememberMe=$session->get('rememberMe');
            $email=$rememberMe->getemail();
            $password=$rememberMe->getpassword();
            $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('mail'=>$email,'password'=>$password));

            if($user)
            {

                return $this-
     >render('gestionBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('user'=>$user));
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('gestionBundle:Default:login.html.twig',array('fr'=>$form->createView()));

}
}
```

**My Twig File:**

My TWIG file is all OK, because I have already succeeded to turning the function 'loginAction' without any problemes !.
I don't know what's wrong in the 'loginAction' Function ?

Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if ($request->getMethod()=='POST'){
```

for this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer..I commit an error while implementing the logout method .                                                                                                    requirements:
          _method: POST                                                                                                    probleme in my Routing.yml  & Security.yml file                                                     resolved :)